# Virtualizing fopen with some malloc-ed memory instead of using a file

Tags: c, unit-testing, serialization, virtualization, fwrite

I have a piece of code using a `FILE* file` with a fwrite:

```
test = fwrite(&object,sizeof(object),1,file);
```

I want to serialize some internal data structure with an indexing structure (so, I'm using neither Google's Protobuf nor Cap'n Proto, since that is a custom data structure with some specific indexing requirements). Now, inside my project, I want to use Google Test in order to test the serialization, in order to check that what it has been serialized it could be deserialized and easily retrieved, too. In the testing phase, I want to pass to fwrite a FILE* object which is not a file, but a handler to some allocated main memory, so that no file is procuded, and that I can directly check the main memory for the results of the serialization. Is it possible to virtualize the `FILE*` and to write directly into the main memory? I would like to keep fwrite for writing data structures for performance reasons, without being forced to write two different methods for serialization (Sometimes i'm writing on the fly with no further memory occupation for transcoding). Thanks in advance.

Comment: `fwrite` is not really serializing (and it won't serialize non-POD objects). If you want to write in memory, just use `memcpy`, but only on POD objects.

Comment: Everything is a POD object inside my structure, plus, I want not to rewirte the code as both fwrite and memcpy.

Comment: in that case, you could create a layer which either writes into a file or in memory (memfile), and use that il all your programs. That would be a nice idea.

Comment: Where can I find such memfiles?

Comment: @jackb Google it, and if you don't find anything it's easy to write your own `Myfwrite`.

Comment: Actually, I remember that there are some ways in C to virtualize some read, write, open and close operations, but I forgot how to do that. It should be something from the gnu c library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fopencookie` did the job I was looking for.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopencookie.3.html

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a dynamic library with all those fopen/fwrite functions (that would do something for your magic filename and fall back to the original ones otherwise) and load it with LD_PRELOAD. To fall back to the originals, resolve them with "dlsym" and RTLD_NEXT.

Another way is to include a special header at the top of the library/test which would have a statement like "#define fopen my_fopen". Inside the file with the implementation of "my_fopen" you need to put "#undef fopen" before including original "stdio.h". This approach will only work for your source code files that include the header but will not hook the functions for the binary libraries that you link.